# list all subsets of $\{a,\{b,c\}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've got to list all subsets of $M=\{a,\{b,c\}\}$.

Does it matter that $\{b,c\}$ is already a subset?

My first few:

$\{\{\}\}$

$\{\{\},a\}$

$\{\{\},a,\{b,c\}\}$

$\{\{\},\{b,c\}\}$

and so on. Is this right?

Comment: Your set has two elements, so its power set has four.  In this case:  $\emptyset, \{a\},\{(b,c)\},\{a,(b,c)\}$.

Comment: When you write a set (*or a subset for that matter*), enclose it in brackets (*unless you are referring to the set symbolically by its name, such as $\emptyset$ or $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb Z$ etc...*)

Comment: @JMoravitz like i edited it now? My questions is kinda: has every subset the empty set in it by definition?

Comment: The emptyset is always a **subset** of any other set, however the emptyset **is not always an element** of a set.  Being a subset and being an element of a set are two very different properties.

Comment: Each of the four sets you listed has $\{\}$ as an element. Is $\{\}$ an ***ELEMENT*** of $M?$ If not, then your sets can't be subsets of $M.$

Comment: @bof so on these excercises i have to: list all combinations of "real" subsets and additionally the emtpy set and the set itself?

Comment: If by "real" subsets you mean proper non-empty subsets, then sure, however I don't think it is good to refer to those as the "real" ones because it implies that somehow the emptyset and the set itself are somehow not "real."

Comment: @JMoravitz yes, sorry i meant proper subsets. (in german it indeed means "real")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. First, any subset of $M$ is in particular a set itself so is enclosed by brackets like $\{$ and $\}$. Subsets are not lists. Second as well as the empty set (which is a subset of $M$), all the elements of any subset of $M$ must belong to $M$. Your set $M$ has 2 elements in it, so the subsets of $M$ will be the empty set, sets with only one element in them (and this element must also belong to $M$) and sets with only 2 elements in them (and again these two elements must also belong to $M$. Will there be subsets with three elements in them? So how many subsets are there of $M$? So now you can write each of the subsets down, remember that each subset is a set and so enclosed in set brackets (as mentioned above).

Comment: so basicly lulu's answer "$\emptyset, \{a\},\{(b,c)\},\{a,(b,c)\}$" was it. And to your question: no there won't be subsets with 3 elements, since M only has 2 elements. There are therefor: 2 "small" subsets, the set itself (in this example), and the empty set. so 4 subsets. Thanks.

Comment: You have got it spot on

Comment: Just a "nit-pick": lulu didn't have it quite right:  $(b, c)$ is an ordered pair, and is not the same thing as $\{b, c\}$. Note that $M$ contains two elements: $a$, and the set $\{b, c\}.\;$ (Yes, a set can be an element, as we see in the set $M).\;$ So, as I said in my answer, the subsets of $M$ are $\varnothing, \;\{a\},\;\{\{b,c\}\},\{a,\{b,c)\}\}$$

Comment: @amWhy thanks for pointing it out, but i already thought that. i just did't recognize that the brackets where unsquirly hehe.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be **any** two-element set; say $M=\{x,y\}$ where $x\ne y.$ A subset $S\subseteq M$ is determined by the answers to two questions: Is $x\in S?$ Is $y\in S?$

Yes/Yes: $S=\{x,y\}$
Yes/No: $\ S=\{x\}$
No/Yes: $\ S=\{y\}$
No/No: $\ \ S=\{\}$

In your case $x=a$ and $y=\{b,c\},$ and I guess we're supposed to assume that $a\ne\{b,c\}.$ Then the four subsets are:

Yes/Yes: $\{a,\{b,c\}\}$
Yes/No: $\ \{a\}$
No/Yes: $\ \{\{b,c\}\}$
No/No: $\ \ \{\}$

Comment: why do we have to assume that $a\ne\{b,c\}.$? Would there be different subsets if $M=\{1,\{1,1\}\}$?

Comment: $M=\{1,\{1,1\}\}$ is an instance of $a=b=c$ but it is ***not*** an instance of $a=\{b,c\}$ because $1\ne\{1,1\}=\{1\}.$

Comment: Suppose $b=1,\ c=2,$ and $a=\{b,c\}=\{1,2\}.$ Then $M=\{a,\{b,c\}\}=\{a,a\}=\{a\}=\{\{1,2\}\}$ is a one-element set and it has only two subsets: itself and the empty set.

Answer (score 1):

$M=\{a,\{b,c\}\}$.

> "Does it matter that $\{b,c\}$ is already a subset?"

**Answer:**

$\;\{b, c\}$ is an **element** of $M$, **but not a subset** of $M.$ That is $\{b, c\} \in M$ but $\;\{b, c\} \not\subset M$

---

$M$ has **two elements**: $a, \;\;\{b, c\}$

---

The subsets of $M$ are as follow:

- The empty set $\{\;\}$ is a subset of every set, and so it is a subset of $M$.
- $\{a\} \subset M$
- $\{\{b, c\}\} \subset M$
- Finally, $\{a, \{b, c\}\} \subseteq M$

Comment: $\{b,c\}$ is not a subset of $M$ ***unless*** $a=b=c.$

Comment: I specifically stated that $\{b, c\}$ is am **element** of M, **but not a subset** of M. And, if a = b=c, then $ \{\{b, c\}\}= \{\{a\}\} \subset M$. @bof

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. In your answer you stated categorically that $\{b,c\}$ is not a subset of $M;$ In my comment I pointed out that that assertion depends on an unstated assumption that $a,b,c$ are not all the same.

Comment: @bof  Even if $a = b= c$, the **element** $\{ b, c\}$, becomes the element $\{a\} \neq a$.  And so the subsets would be $\varnothing$, $\{a\}$, $\{\{a\}\}$, and $M$ itself.  That is, $a\neq \{a\}$

Comment: So what? What does your comment have to do with anything I said? The whole, sole, only, and entire point of my initial comment was to point out that the assertion "$\{b,c\}$ is not a subset of $M$" requires an assumption which was not stated.

Comment: Good night, dear @bof